# Ubuntu server 14.04: apache2 cannot start

Tags: apache, ubuntu-14.04

I install apache2 and it works fine , and make it work for two days , after that I reboot the server.

Then I cant' restart the apache2

service apache2 restart

```
     * Restarting web server apache2                               [fail] 
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/setenvif.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_setenvif.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_setenvif.so: cannot open shared object file: Input/output error
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

I didn't know what is the problem , if you can help me to solve it^_^

Comment: It seems its having trouble loading a module. Have you installed any apache modules lately?

Comment: No , just enable rewrite module

Comment: have you modified the config? either `.htaccess` or any `.conf`? What version of apache are you running? Im assuming 2.4.x because your on 14.04

Comment: No , i didn't remember any thing , I changed